# Puzzling .Net C# DeflateStream problem

Tags: c#, .net, deflate, deflatestream

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on an issue that is driving me nuts:

I am writing a compression decompression test class.  To test it, I am serializing a dataset to a memory stream, compressing it, and uncompressing it and comparing the results.

Compression is fine, but uncompression is where it hits the dirt. 
This is the decompress function:

```
    public static Stream GetUncompressedStreamCopy(Stream inStream)
    {
      Stream outStream = new MemoryStream();

      inStream.Position = 0;

      DeflateStream uncompressStream = new DeflateStream(inStream, 
        CompressionMode.Decompress, true);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

      int totalread = 0;
      int bytesread = 0;


      do {
        bytesread = uncompressStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        totalread += bytesread;
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
        Console.WriteLine("bytesRead: [{0}]\t outStream.Length [{1}]",
        bytesread, outStream.Length);
      } while (bytesread > 0);


      Console.WriteLine("total bytes read [{0}]", totalread);
      outStream.Flush();
      return outStream;
}
```

With a buffer of size 65536 the decompressed stream always returns one byte less than it was uncompressed.

Now this brings me to the second issue which I am battling with.  With some buffer sizes, uncompressStream.Read returns 0 even though there is still compressed data left to extract.

For these cases, deflateStream.Read(s) only once in the do{} loop and then returns an uncompressed stream equal to buffersize, if you increase the buffersize by a single byte all is well (except for the missing byte).

Output for buffersize of 65536:  (Original uncompressed data is 207833)

```
bytesRead: [65536]       outStream.Length [65536]
bytesRead: [65536]       outStream.Length [131072]
bytesRead: [58472]       outStream.Length [189544]
bytesRead: [18288]       outStream.Length [207832]
bytesRead: [0]           outStream.Length [207832]
total bytes read [207832]
```

buffersize of 189544 (Some magic number where the code tanks)

```
bytesRead: [189544]      outStream.Length [189544]
bytesRead: [0]           outStream.Length [189544]
total bytes read [189544]
Unompressed stream size 189544
```

Also note the 3rd read of buffersize 65536 ex: bytesRead: [58472]  Clearly this should also be 65536 as there still data left on the buffer?

Any ideas will be *greatly* appreciated.

tia

- Jaco

Comment: How can you say that compression is fine if you can't decompress the data?

Comment: Hi Lasse,

I have written another implementation where the compressed size of the same dataset equals the size of the stream post compression.
- hope that makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always call Close() on compression streams. Please note that Flush() is **not enough**. I suspect that because of this the deflate stream is missing data.

Comment: At first, Close didn't work because it closed the underlying stream aswell.  But calling .Close() after the deflatestream was created with the true option to leaveOpen I could close it and the underlying stream was passed back to the caller!

tyvm!

Comment: DeflateStream is a Stream, which means it is IDisposable.  You need a using clause. Although Close() may be sufficient, you've violated the usage model by not calling Dispose() or enclosing it in a using clause.

Answer (score 3):

My psychic powers tells me that you do in fact have a working decompression implementation, but have forgotten to flush the compression stream before.

Comment: a DeflateStream.Close() rectified it tyvm

Comment: Can you post a code example of where to put the Close and decompress?
Reading from deflate stream always giving me no data.
But the data should be okay. Maybe it's a different problem though..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't spot your problem, but follow some code I wrote sometime ago for [ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/);

```
byte[] compressedData;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true);
    Stream s = new DeflaterOutputStream(ms, deflater);
    s.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
    s.Close();
    compressedData = (byte[])ms.ToArray();
}

// ...

MemoryStream inflated = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream inflater = new InflaterInputStream(
    inputStream, new Inflater(true)))
{
    int count = 0;
    byte[] deflated = new byte[4096];
    while ((count = inflater.Read(deflated, 0, deflated.Length)) != 0)
    {
        inflated.Write(deflated, 0, count);
    }
    inflated.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
byte[] content = new byte[inflated.Length];
inflated.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
```